# user accessing another site collection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

a web application is having 3 site collection named SC1, SC2, SC3. Now these 3 SC has their own content database, where only user from sc1 can access its own content. Like that same for SC2 & SC3.

Now the requirement is few selected user from SC1 wants to access 2 list of SC2, similarly, few selected user from SC2 wants to access 2 list of SC3 .

is this possible OOB? or by some other means?

any light on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want some users from SC1 to access the whole SC2, then you will have to add them to the *Visitors* group of SC2.

If you want them to access only one or two lists from SC2, then you should go to those lists, go to their permission settings, choose *Break inheritance* and then add those *selected* users to the list with appropriate permissions. You could even create a Sharepoint Group on the site collection level and add that group to the lists with the appropriate permissions and add your users directly to the group. This would save you much trouble when in the future you would have to give access to the same users on a different list of SC2 or if you should grant access to one more user. You could just simply add him/her to this Sharepoint Group and would automatically have the same access levels like the rest.

I hope this answered your question.